# log4net is not writing logs to file

Tags: log4net

I have the following code to write a log item to a file. It creates the file correctly but there is never anything in the file (ie it is always 0 bytes in size). What am I doing wrong?

```
           ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("mainlog");
            RollingFileAppender logAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
            string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingFilePath"];

            filePath = filePath + "EventLog.csv";


            logAppender.File = filePath;
            logAppender.AppendToFile = true;
            logAppender.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
            logAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups = 60;
            logAppender.StaticLogFileName = true;

            log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(logAppender);
            logAppender.ActivateOptions();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(applicationID.ToString());
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(itemName);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(itemException.Message);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(itemException.StackTrace);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(itemException.Source);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(itemException.TargetSite);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(itemEventType.ToString());

            log.Debug(sb.ToString());

            logAppender.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the layout, for example

```
 logAppender.Layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout(
     "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline");
```